# Android Nougat Wi-Fi drop after updating Galaxy Note5

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-note

I'm using Galaxy Note5 and updated my phone via Software Update option in my phone and my phone is not rooted. So, i keep the Wi-Fi always on while its sleeping but, in the battery section, when i select wi-fi from the battery using programs&apps list, i just see here "Turn off Wi-Fi when not in use.". Also when my phone goes sleep after 2 mins of wait, i just waited like 5 mins or 10 mins i don't know the exact time, when i wake it up , just saw the wi-fi connected again every time, but as i said i selected always on from the settings.I also tried reset all network settings etc. and tried to find Wi-Fi from apps to prevent it from the power saving but there is no Wi-Fi. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.[image][image]